Peewee ORM: JSONField when database engine can switch dynamically
I really like peewee, and use it extensively; our software uses .bind to be able to switch SQLite databases, and that works great. We need to switch databases because our software is mostly for researchers for have multiple projects, we we give each project a subdirectory with their own database.
After 12 years, we would like to refactor the database to put most data in a JSONField column, and support Postgres in addition to SQLite. However, I am not sure how to do this without evil hacks - the extension classes for JSONField are very different across these two engines.
Is there a way to write a generic class which includes a JSONField column whose behaviour can be modified at run-time in Peewee? Even a hint in the right direction would be enough to get started.
